# Play Session Management

Tags: playframework

In Play, the session id is being passed from the ajax call for every request. Back-end validates the session.

This approach looks to be wrong. Is this is a right approach?

Please advise whether what would be the best approach

**First approach**

1. Generate cookie from client, Pass on to the server first time during login
2. Server saves the cookie and check for expiration using interceptor
3. Have both client side and server side expiration for cookie.

**Second approach**

1. First request from client on login, server generates auth token and send to client
2. Each request the client appends the auth token
3. Auth token has expiry on the server side.

Thanks.